# Problem with fetch calls and promise chaining

Tags: javascript, promise, fetch-api

**edit: was a problem on the backend

So I've been having a problem with chaining promises. I ditched axios and async await to go back to re-learn the basics, as I must be making a simple mistake somewhere, but I've had no luck. Was hoping someone could take a look?

I'm calling the following routes in the following order:

1. `/users/register`
2. `/users/all`
3. `/delete/:id`
4. `/users/all`

The problem is that the code should add a user, and then delete that same user, but I'd say 1 in every 6 or so calls, both step 2 and step 4 (displaying all users) show the newly added user - which isn't correct.

But as far as I can see I'm chaining the promises and calls together correctly.

I must be missing something obvious, but I really can't see it. Would appreciate a second pair of eyes or direction as to where I'm going wrong

```
    function test() {
        fetch(`http://localhost:8080/users/register`, {        **//1**
            method: 'POST',
            mode: 'cors',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ firstName: 'nick', lastName: 'smith', phone: '01980635243', email: 'nick@hotmail.com', password: '1234567891011', confirmPassword:'1234567891011'})
        })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res);
            return fetch('http://localhost:8080/users/all')    **//2**
        })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res)
            return fetch('http://localhost:8080/users/delete-email/nick@hotmail.com', {  **//3**
                method: 'DELETE',
                mode: 'cors',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }
            });
        })
        .then(res => res.json()) 
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res)
            return fetch('http://localhost:8080/users/all');    **//4**
        })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(res => console.log(res))
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
    }
```

Comment: They're chained just fine, but are you wanting to keep the results of all of them? Would it be better to not chain them and fire them all off in an array and Promise.all?

Comment: Are you sure this has anything to do with fetch/promises? if in the end, all the actions were performed, then it's more likely the server's response to your GET isn't as consistent as you're expecting it to be.

Comment: Not entirely no, perhaps it could be on the server side, but every time I test the individual routes it seems to work. I guess at least if I know the above code is correct I can start focusing on that instead.

Comment: @evolutionxbox you cannot run these in parallel. they must be run in sequence as each promise depends on the result of the previous action..

Comment: I just can't see how step 4 could return the same number of array values - I'm getting the correct response from the server, and I can see that it's being deleted  - so surely it has to be a promise issue? The above is the only code other than calling `test()`.

Comment: These client requests are all chained/sequenced just fine.  So, if one of the calls isn't returning the expected values, then it's entirely a server issue or you are confused about what exactly is being logged (since none of your `console.log()` statements are labelled so you can tell which is which.  Oh, and by the way, this is a classic example of code that would look a lot simpler if you use `await` to sequence things.

Comment: Yeah it must be. The confirmation saves me a lot of headache. Thanks, I'll vote to close this as it'll be no use to anyone else

Comment: @jfriend00 yeah but I was also having this problem with await :) And no, the console.logs are outputting either the array or the server response so it's pretty clear in the console (although I did consider console.log lying to me...)

Comment: @jfriend00 took me all of 5 minutes to find the problem - hours later - once I knew it wasn't the client side. Wasn't chaining `user.destroy()` on the backend. Silly mistake

Comment: @NickW - Yep, that is the type of thing that would do it.  So, you had a race condition between different requests.  Would work sometimes and not work other times.  I guess you can answer your own question then.

Answer (score -1):

Good for you to take a step back and really focus on learning the basics. You should know that `fetch` is a low-level interface and it's a rookie move to use it as-is. Programming is all about making your life easier. If you need to deal with JSON, let's write a `fetchJSON` specialization -

```js
const fetchJson = (url, opts = {}) =>
  fetch(url, { ...opts, headers: 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
    .then(r => r.json())
```

Even with our helper, we shouldn't jump to use it directly. By defining reusable functions, our code becomes more descriptive and easier to use -

```js
const userList = () =>
  fetchJson(`http://localhost:8080/users/all`)
```

Creating the `userRegister` function is easy too -

```js
const userRegister = (user = {}) =>
  fetchJson
    ( `http://localhost:8080/users/register`
    , { method: "POST", mode: "cors", body: JSON.stringify(user) }
    )
```

And finally `userDelete` -

```js
const userDelete = email =>
  fetchJson
    ( `http://localhost:8080/users/delete-email/${email}`
    , { method: "DELETE", mode: "cors" }
    )
```

Now we can put it all together

```js
const test = () =>
  userRegister({
    firstName: 'nick',
    lastName: 'smith',
    phone: '01980635243',
    email: 'nick@hotmail.com',
    password: '1234567891011',
    confirmPassword:'1234567891011'
  })
  .then(user => {
    console.log("registered", user)
    return userList()
  })
  .then(users => {
    console.log("list", users)
    return userDelete("nick@hotmail.com")
  })
  .then(_ =>
    console.log("user deleted")
    return userList()
  })
```

Notice we don't attach any `.catch` to the `test`. This is left for the caller to decide. We could run the test like this -

```js
test().then(console.log, console.error)
```

**don't stop there**

Do you see the pattern of `.then(something => { console.log(something), ... })`. We *could* make a generic `log` function that makes this intention more clear -

```js
const log = label => data =>
{ console.log(label, data)
  return data
}

const test = () =>
  userRegister({
    firstName: 'nick',
    lastName: 'smith',
    phone: '01980635243',
    email: 'nick@hotmail.com',
    password: '1234567891011',
    confirmPassword:'1234567891011'
  })
  .then(log("registered"))
  .then(_ => userList())
  .then(log("list"))
  .then(_ => userDelete("nick@hotmail.com"))
  .then(log("user deleted"))
  .then(_ => userList())
```

But there's a bad practice here. `console.log` is a side effect and it would be nice if we could get the result of *each* promise back from the `test`. We can plainly see that `_ => ...` is *replacing* the value of the previous promise in the chain and only the *final* promise value will be available to the caller.

You *could* append all the results to an array and thread the array through to each successive promise, but this is also rather tedious. This is particularly where `async` and `await` are helpful as they make promise values available in the same scope -

```js
async function test()
{ const user = await userRegister({
    firstName: 'nick',
    lastName: 'smith',
    phone: '01980635243',
    email: 'nick@hotmail.com',
    password: '1234567891011',
    confirmPassword:'1234567891011'
  })

  const list1 = await userList()

  const delete = await userDelete("nick@hotmail.com")

  const list2 = await userList()

  return [user, list1, deleted, list2] // <- all results
}
```

Now `console.log` has been disentangled from `test` and the result of *all* promise values is available to the caller

```js
test().then(console.log, console.error)
```

Comment: How does this answer the OP's question?

Comment: Interesting read, thanks, but I'm just going back to using axios instances now. I was just using fetch so that I could follow a really basic guide and make sure that wasn't where the problem was!

Comment: @jfriend00 the answer is not to use `fetch` that way

Comment: @NickW `axios` is low-level the exact same way `fetch` is. You will make the same mistake by using `axios` directly every time you need to make a request. Writing specializations of `fetch`/`axios` like I demonstrated in this post is specifically aimed at reducing the probability of making a mistake in your code. This is because using `fetch` and `axios` requires extra steps every time you touch it and that's incredible potential for introducing errors in your code.

Comment: What "mistake" or "bug" is there in the OP's code in their question?  Yes, the OP is not writing DRY code at all, but there's nothing actually wrong with their code that I see that is relevant to the question.  And, the actual problem turned out to be on the server-side, not in this client code.  I don't see how your answer actually fixes anything.  Yes, it reorganizes the code and makes it prettier, but what does it actually fix and therefore, back to my question - How does the answer the OP's question?

Comment: It appears you have an "opinion" on how `fetch()` should be coded just like there are 1000 ways to write any piece of code - I myself would write this code in a much more DRY way.  I just can't find any relation between that opinion and the actual question the OP asked.

Comment: @jfriend00 well you're answering your own question. The problem is not the client but it's impossible (very difficult) to see because there's a heaping wall of code where errors *could* exist. By writing reusable functions you make it hard for bugs to hide in the code: you can look at the client and immediately rule it out as a suspect.

Comment: Well, if the point of your answer is to "clean-up" the client code so it's easier to make sure you aren't accidentally making a mistake in the client code, then your answer should start with that and state that as the purpose of the answer. The text in the answer implies that one has to do all this to fix things, yet never actually points out why this will or won't fix anything.  Since your answer isn't really about fixing what was being asked about, I'll skip my feedback on your coding suggestions as I have some things to agree with and some things to disagree with there.

Comment: _"... then your answer should start with that"_ fair point, I guess. We'd be in big trouble if doctors relied on the accuracy of patient questions to give proper medical help. My diagnosis of the problem is that the client code is off to a bad start and making these changes will make it nearly impossible for bugs to exist. If things still don't work after that, then it's obvious to hunt for the bug elsewhere. Sorry I didn't spell that out explicitly.